Vue & Supabase: Server-side user deletion not triggering client logout
I am using Supabase with Vue to handle authentication in my app. It seems like Supabase does not fire an auth event for user deletion, which seems odd to me.
Here is my scenario: I log in with user123 in my app, which causes an auth state change, and my app redirects me to the members page. I visit the Supabase dashboard and delete user123. No auth event is fired and user123 remains logged in. I can visit other routes as user123, including the restricted members route. Logging out and in again results in a login error (as expected since user123 no longer exists).
Is this expected behaviour? How do I handle this scenario so a deleted user (deleted from the Supabase dashboard, not from the client/app) gets logged out? Polling the server would work, but surely there is a better way.
